# Found a issue with watermark. It adds a 1 pixel black line at the bottom of image, when backgound of uses light color

Tags: mlt

[Source image does not contain bottom black line [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5JLf.png)

Comment: Can you post the melt command that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Please check carefully every watermark image has unexpected black line on bottom.
melt be1.mp4 -filter watermark:t.png composite.start=100/25:100%x100% -filter watermark:t.png composite.start=100/100:100%x100% -filter watermark:t.png composite.start=100/200:100%x100% -consumer avformat:out.mp4
http://www.improsys.com/melt/t.png
http://www.improsys.com/melt/be1.mp4
http://www.improsys.com/melt/out.mp4